# Need performance improvement

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am trying out CasperJS. I am trying to create a web **scraper** . I need to **scrape** all pages of site(s) and get data in less than 5 seconds(each page).
For this I will have to crawl through all similar pages. Go to appropriate content div and get data from there.
So If the site has say 1000 pages. I need to complete whole operation as quickly as possible. I can not control N/w latency, page size etc parameter. All I can control is parsing mechanism. So I want it to be as fast as possible. If there is even small improvement, then it will extrapolate as the number of URLs

I am trying to parse child elements and creating CSS paths.
I need to make sure parsing does not take long time.
I hear standard java-script is more efficient in terms of performance than JQuery.
Hence, I need inputs.

What will be the standard JS equivalent of following JQuery code, which performance efficient in terms of parsing.

```
function() {    
    var TAG_CSS_PATH = 'div#buttons ul li.tab';
    var selectOptions =  $(TAG_CSS_PATH);
    var results = [],i=0;
    selectOptions.each(function(index,value) {
        index=index+1;
        results.push(TAG_CSS_PATH+':nth-of-type('+index+')');
    });
    return results
}
```

If anybody can provide any other suggestions, I will appreciate it.

Comment: why don't you try converting it, then we can help.

Comment: It is a naive question to ask. But I need inputs on performance as well.

Comment: performance doesn't matter without context. and jQuery is pretty good as far as performance goes as well. You should only worry about performance if you try something and it's actually too slow.

Comment: Actually, @kennypu: jQuery sucks compared to native JS, on performance.

Comment: Do not know why, but querySelectorAll(TAG_CSS_PATH) is known to perform faster than any other Jquery selectors. I did search on the answer provided by @Cerbrus.

Comment: @SaurabhV it would be very interesting to know why you are looking for this small optimization in your code. I'm not convinced that this will contribute a lot to solving performance problems.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
function() {    
    var TAG_CSS_PATH = 'div#buttons ul li.tab',
        selectOptions = document.querySelectorAll(TAG_CSS_PATH),
        results = [],
        l = selectOptions.length + 1;
    for(var i = 1; i < l; i++){
        results.push(TAG_CSS_PATH+':nth-of-type('+i+')');
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: For micro optimisation, take the selectOptions.length outside of the for loop

Comment: You're missing on the 'index+1'

Comment: @EricG: this code must be the correct answer then :P Now it's just a matter of preference: `l = X` in or outside of the `for`.

Comment: Agreed ;) usually I do variables, needed once & only in the loop, in the declaration (unless it becomes long & unreadable, but length is usually just the only extra variable)

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery part is the $selector, and the $each. These can be replaced as follows.

```
function() {    
    var TAG_CSS_PATH = '#buttons ul li.tab',
        selectOptions =  document.querySelectorAll(TAG_CSS_PATH),
        results = [];

    for( var i = 1, ln = selectOptions.length + 1; i < ln; i++ ) {
        results.push(TAG_CSS_PATH+':nth-of-type('+ i +')');
    }

    return results;
}
```

Since you are storing selectors, it seems still really inefficient to me (usage of nth-of-type are expensive selectors). Selectors are read from right to left.

**CSS/selector optimisation**
Note,
the `div#buttons` seems redundant. If you use CSS properly, you will have only exactly *one* element that matches `id='buttons'`. Thus, with proper use of IDs, you should be able to remove the `div` in the selector.
Further, if all your `.tab`s are `li`, then you can remove the `li`, too. If all your  `li.tab`s are inside `ul`, you can remove the `ul` too.

Comment: But I need the array of selectors later in code. Is there faster way than nth-of-type. OR may be other approach to do it. I looked in to XPaths. But I do not know it will be faster than CSS Paths.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you are planning to use them later on? Because different usages might lead to different optimal solutions.

Comment: Sure. I am trying out CasperJS. I am trying to create a webscrapper for a specific site. I need to scrap all pages of site and get data in less than 5 seconds. For this I will have to crawl through all similiar pages. Go to appropriate content div and get data from there. So If the site has say 1000 pages. I need to complete whole operation as quickly as possible. I can not control N/w latency, page size etc paramenter. All I can control is parsing mechenism. So I want it to be as fast as possible. If there is even small improvement, then it will extrapolate as the number of URLs.

Comment: I used to work on HtmlUnit and Selenium for testing purpose. It is Java based. But I recently had to move to CasperJS. It is faster as compared to both of them JavaScript based.

Comment: I see. My bad, but, I was more specifically aiming at where you would use your results. Can you add that to your post..?

Comment: Forgive me, but I would like to see where you use the `results` in code. You collect selectors, but you haven't posted yet where you use them in JS. Where do you invoke this function..?